# Determining if function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I have no idea how to proceed with the following question.

''Let $f$ be an analytic function in the unit disk. Define:
$$G(z)=\int_0^zf(w)\sin(z+w)~dw$$

Is $G(z)$ analytic? If so, in what region?"

How do I even begin with a question like this? Since everything in the integral is analytic, does that make $G$ analytic as well, over however large $z$ is?

Comment: Yes, integration preserves analyticity. (Reason: power series can be integrated term by term).

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(z+w)$ (as a function of $w$) is entire, hence analytic in the unit disk. The class of analytic functions in the unit disk is closed under multiplication, differentiation and integration - you can easily check that by manipulating power series, hence $G(z)$ is analytic in the unit disk.

We cannot say more since $f(z)$ may have a non-integrable singularity (a pole or worse) somewhere outside the unit disk.